# Angular does not recognise item from keyvalue pipe on ng build --prod

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to use the [keyvalue pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe) in my production Angular application

I have some data like this (basic example - not actual data)

```
{
    01-12-19: [
        {
            message: 'hello',
            id: 12
        },
        {
            message: 'goodbye',
            id: 13
        }
    ],
    02-12-19: [
        {
            message: 'hello',
            id: 14
        },
        {
            message: 'goodbye',
            id: 15
        }
    ]
}
```

now in my component HTML I am trying to use the `| keyvalue` pipe like so

```
<div *ngFor="let item of messages | keyvalue | orderBy: item?.key">
    <div class="date">
        {{item?.key | momentFormat: 'DD/MM/YYYY'}}
    </div>
    <app-message
        *ngFor="let message of item?.value"
        [message]="message"
    >
    </app-message>
</div>
```

now this works, I can see the list of messages.

But when I try and build my project with `ng build --prod` I keep getting these errors

```
Property 'item' does not exist on type 'MessageContainerComponent'
```

How can I fix this issue? This error does not show up when I run `ng build` only errors on production.

Comment: Where did you import the pipe ? Can you upload the module that import the pipe ?

Comment: @TonyNgo its a default angular pipe not a custom pipe, so it does not need importing https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe its a part of the common module

Comment: Can you create stackblitz demo so I can take a look at ?

Comment: @TonyNgo not sure how a stackblitz would help since you cant build the angular project from there..

Comment: @Smokey Dawson Please check document https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe

Comment: Or github would may help if you dont mind. Because I only see small piece of your code so I cant tell

Comment: @chintankotadiya I am not using the default angular orderBy pipe I am using https://github.com/VadimDez/ngx-order-pipe

Comment: @SmokeyDawson read the link. Angular doesn't have a "default order pipe", it **insists on the fact you must not use one**.

Comment: as for your error, it's because you use `item` as a pipe parameter, while defining it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to replicate that issue in local and I face the same issue. I have resolved that like that way.

I have checked also in production mode.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of messages | keyvalue | orderBy: messages.item">
    <div class="date">
        {{item.key | momentFormat: 'DD/MM/YYYY'}}
    </div>
    <app-message
        *ngFor="let message of item.value"
        [message]="message"
    >
    </app-message>
</div>
```

Please try that way. hope this will help you.